# Problem is context: I display localization .arb file values in List<DataListed> listData[] and in AppLocalizations.of(context)!.all_notes

Tags: flutter, dart

Problem is context error: I want to display localization .arb file values in List listData[] and in AppLocalizations.of(context)!.all_notes take error context

I want to localization .arb file values in List and in AppLocalizations.of(context)!.all_notes take context error.

You can see error in Image
[Showing Error in Imge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPkV1.jpg)
In AppLocalizations.of(context)!.all_notes solution for contexterror

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DataListed> listData(BuildContext context) {
    return [
        DataListed(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.all_note1),
        DataListed(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.all_note2),
    ];
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?